# rails 3.2.6 opening rails console error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with rails 3.2.6 while opening rails console i am getting error as showing below please tell me the solution.

/home/rajani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
    from /home/rajani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in`'

Answer (score 1):

It's depends on which platform you're using. Run `rvm requirements` and install readline library appropriately to solve the problem, like `rvm pkg install readline` before installing ruby.